# Filter a split form using a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am filtering a split form using a textbox called txtSearch. In the After Update event of the textbox, I have inserted the following macro:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()

On Error GoTo CleanFail

    If Nz(Me.txtSearch.Text, "") = "" Then
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.txtSearch.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Filter = "Produktnamn like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or ATC like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Företag like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Statustxt like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Enhetsnamn like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or FullName like '" & _
        Me.txtSearch.Text + "*'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus
    Me.txtSearch.SelStart = Len(Nz(Me.txtSearch.Text, "")) + 1


CleanExit:
    Exit Sub


CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 2158 Then
        Err.Clear
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Resume CleanExit
    End If

End Sub
```

I am able to filter the data in the split form when I insert text into txtSearch. However, upon emptying the textbox to show all records again, the filter is disabled ONLY in those instances where the previous search was a success. In other words, if I type something into the textbox for which there are no matching records, there will still be no records shown even after emptying the textbox.

Comment: Did you try to add a `Me.Requery` in your sub ? I would place it just after `Me.FilterOn = False` first, in order to see I get all my records back after emptying textbox.

Comment: Still doesn't work - no records returned after emptying the textbox...

Comment: In the `if NZ()`, try to reset the filter : `Me.Filter = ""` and requery

Comment: If Nz(Me.txtSearch.Text, "", Me.Filter = "")? Not quite sure what you mean but I tried a few different ways and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of `If Me.Recordset.EOF And Me.Recordset.BOF Then Me.FilterOn = False` appears to have solved my problem.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()

On Error GoTo CleanFail

If Me.Recordset.EOF And Me.Recordset.BOF Then
      Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
    Me.Filter = "Produktnamn like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or ATC like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Företag like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Statustxt like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or Enhetsnamn like '" + Me.txtSearch.Text + "*' or FullName like '" & _
        Me.txtSearch.Text + "*'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus
    Me.txtSearch.SelStart = Len(Nz(Me.txtSearch.Text, "")) + 1
End If

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub


CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 2158 Then
        'handle the error - msgbox, whatever
        Err.Clear
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Resume CleanExit
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset also the `.Filter` property:

```
If Nz(Me.txtSearch.Text, "") = "" Then
    Me.Filter = ""      ' <- add this
    Me.FilterOn = False
```

Also, in your error handler you should have a way to handle all errors, not just that particular one. Otherwise they will simply be ignored.

```
CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 2158 Then
        Err.Clear
        Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, "Runtime Error " & Err.Number
    End If
    Resume CleanExit
```

Comment: Still having the exact same problem.